# tlmgr not working after update

Tags: tlmgr, perl

After some general system update, tlmgr stopped working.
Everything I try gives the follwing error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl: config.guess script does not exist, goodbye:
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/../../tlpkg/installer/config.guess at
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 321.
```

Any Idea what went wrong? How could I troubleshoot this? I assume something within the perl installation changed? Is it possible to reinstall just tlmgr, without all of TexLive?

Comment: General system updates should not remove files from `/usr/local/texlive/2023`. So if `/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/config.guess` is really missing, something seems to be fundamentally broken. Maybe [`update-tlmgr-latest.sh`](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh) would fix this issue. But maybe your TeX Live is broken to bad and you've to install a new one. Here, with an up-to-date 2023, `tlmgr` works as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cabohah The config.guess is in fact not missing and where it should be. The update script could not solve the problem.

Comment: AFAIK vanilla TeX Live's `tlmgr` usually does not use a `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm` but `/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm`. So maybe it is an issue with search path settings and a parallel installation of texlive packages of your linux distribution or whatever installed `/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/TeXLive/…`.